# Windows 8 Metro Bing Maps Beta Image

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, bing-maps

My XAML / C# app has a beta image on my map:

[image]

Am I using the wrong SDK? I tried using this one:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c341dfb-4584-4738-949c-daf55b82df58

I received a WinRT exception saying it cannot create an instance of the Bing Maps. I am using this one now:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca

I am using Windows 8 Pro with VS 2012 Ultimate version 11.05 with Windows 8 pro. I am using the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the second link you provided:

> This release is intended for development and testing for apps on
>   Windows 8 RTM builds. *It will not be supported when we release our
>   final build at the end of September.* **This build contains a watermark
>   over the map to denote its pre-release status.** Apps submitted with
>   this build will not pass WACK certification.

Italics and bold added.

To summarize:

You're using a beta version of the sdk which has a watermark in it.  To fix this you will need to wait until they release the "release" version of the sdk at the end of the month.

Comment: Yeah, I'm suffering too. That is one hell of a watermark! Couldn't they make it a bit smaller? Not fun showing this to a client when demonstrating a proof of concept app- it's not exactly *discrete* ;)

Comment: The "final" version is now available from: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca